# Custom textbox doesn't display text

Tags: html, css

I have a text box that has a background on it, i made the div editable but when i type there is nothing there. There is also the issue where the background image is not a complete square so there white at the corners which are really irritating me. is there a way to make the white pieces transparent so the user can only write on the image.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#note").resizable();
            $("#note").draggable();
        });
    </script>
    <title>Stickynote</title>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</head>
<body>
<div id="note" contenteditable="true">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
background-image:url("images/background.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}

html {
height: 100%;
}
html img{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto 

}
#note 
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("images/stickynote.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle and share the link with us..

Comment: dunno if this will help you but this is handy http://jsfiddle.net/qseqadnt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start, we can't see your images. If you want the corners transparent, you should use a PNG. But I imagine your images might have rounded corners, with that you could just use css3's background-radius property.

```
body {
    background: url('http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/always_grey.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
html img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
#note {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/arches.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zh7Ljjev/

On your other issue, you mention the editable div. That seems to be working fine for me, so I can't help you with what's wrong with it. Sometimes I forget to change the text color to a color readable on that background image, but without seeing your background image I can't tell if that's the problem.

Also check the CanIUse to make sure your browser is capable of that: http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

Comment: The image im using is a sticky note like the ones there http://goodpixgallery.com/blank-sticky-note-png-photos/

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention was an error in your code. You don't want to use `<img>` tags outside of the body element. It could be that that error is causing your other issues. Does your editable text field work in the jsfiddle I made?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make the image transparent with css

```
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

[Refer](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) document..

Comment: I see but the problem is that makes the background image transparent too

Answer (score 0):

You should have some content in your `<div>`. Try to put a placeholder in it: "Please, enter your description here..."

Answer (score 0):

I have add new class `#note  div`, please check it and let me know.

**Demo code**

```js
$(function() {
     $("#note").resizable();
     $("#note").draggable();
});
```

```css
body { 
background-image:url("images/background.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}

html {
height: 100%;
}
html img{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto 

}
#note 
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("images/stickynote.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#note  div
{
width: 200px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <title>Stickynote</title>
    <img src="images/logo.png">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="note" contenteditable="true">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```